# Springboot Data JPA : getRowCountByTableName(String tablename)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

I'm developing a Springboot Application. One of the features of this application is to show Database Information (like tablename, no.of records, etc) on the UI. Currently I'm stuck in writing the  implementation for the method `public int getRowCountByTableName(String tablename)`.

There are lot of tables in the database, based on the given name I have to return the rowcount of that table. I have done some research on this and found that Hibernate Criteria API can help.

```
String cName = map.get(tableName);//There is map which has <tableName,CanonicalNameOfTheEntity>
className = Class.forName(cName);           
Criteria cr = dbSession.createCriteria(className);
cr.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
rowCount = (Long) cr.uniqueResult();
```

But the problem is that Hibernate Criteria API is deprecated. So I'm not supposed to use this deprecated api as per my organization policy.

Can someone help me finding an alternative way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hibernate's Criteria API is deprecated, but JPA's Criteria API is not deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50073875/4798347

Does JPA's Criteria API support your use case?

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks for quick response. Yeah, JPA's Criteria API works for me. I thought of using it. Do you foresee if JPA's Criteria API getting deprecated in near future?. And also - Is there any other approach?

Comment: I don't see any reason for JPA to abandon the Criteria API, although I'm admittedly not in any decision-making role regarding JPA's development. As far as alternatives, Spring's JDBC support (particularly `JdbcTemplate`) might fit the bill: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc

Comment: Thanks @Zephyr . I'll go with JPA's Criteria API.